# Rails 3: Including a plugin inside an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I know it sounds kinda nuts, but I'm building an engine that will power and tie several applications, and since all applications will use a given plugin, I was wondering whether I could just put the plugin in the engine.

So I put it inside vendor/plugins, but it appears it isn't loaded.

I've been playing with `autoload_paths` and `require`, but I haven't been successful.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or do you have an idea on what I might try?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "engine" in terms of what you're doing.

Comment: I just created standard Rails Engine and I'm adding it as a gem on each app.

Comment: What rails version are you using? in rails 2.3.* you could use   config.plugin_paths = ["#{Rails.root}/vendor/plugins", "#{YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH}/vendor/plugins"]
 in your environment.rb

Comment: It's Rails 3, so I can't use your approach. I've found I can load the plugin by adding it's lib path to `$:` and requiring the `init.rb` file, but I'm not sure that's right and probably won't work for more complex plugins.

Answer (score 6):

After some fiddling, this is what I found works and seems correct:

```
module MyEngine 
  class Engine < Rails::Engine 
    config.after_initialize do 
      Rails.application.config.paths.vendor.plugins.push File.expand_path('../../vendor/plugins', __FILE__) 
    end 
  end 
end
```